# C++ sending forming and sending JSON structures and posting with CurlLib

Tags: c++, json, curl

This works when its just a standard string with "content=blahblah"

So I have my JSON structure

```
{
  "content": null,
  "embeds": [
    {
      "title": "Login",
      "description": "Key = null",
      "color": null
    }
  ]
}
```

and I think I have put It into C++ JSON correctly

```
json data;
    data = R"(
        {
  "content": null,
  "embeds": [
    {
      "title": "Login",
      "description": "Key = null",
      "color": null
    }
  ]
}
    )"_json;
```

I have my curl code but this is throwing an exception.

```
if (curl) {
        //Set URL that will be posted to
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, webhookURL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        //Set post data
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data.dump().data());
        //Get result
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            std::cout << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
```

ive changed the cpp json again but instead i get a different exception
The exception:

```
{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}
```

Please help, Thanks

Comment: "_this is throwing an exception_" - Care to share it by putting it in the question? My _guess_ is that `data.dump()` is _not_ returning a `char*` and that you need to call a function on the object returned by `dump()`. Possibly: `data.dump().data()`

Comment: @TedLyngmo that still throws an exception, it doesnt give me one exactly cause it just takes me to a file

Comment: ... and I still have no idea what the exception is or what it says

Comment: template<class Exception>
    bool parse_error(std::size_t /*unused*/, const std::string& /*unused*/,
                     const Exception& ex)
    {
        errored = true;
        static_cast<void>(ex);
        if (allow_exceptions)
        {
            JSON_THROW(ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
@TedLyngmo

Comment: `"title"=Login` isn't valid json

Comment: There should be a comma after `Login` and `test` in your JSON

Comment: @jwjw2069 Edit your question and put the exception in full in the question - not in comments

Comment: Btw, why didn't you put the _valid_ JSON that you have at the top of your question and put that in the raw string?

Comment: Ive added the exception into the question and changed the cpp json.

Comment: "_instead i get a different exception_" - Ok, _what_?

Comment: @TedLyngmo
The exception:

{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}

I put it above it

Comment: Do you still use `data.dump()` in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah im using data.dump().data()

Comment: @jwjw2069 I think, you should put yourself in our shoes, we are really confused by the question and your comments. Take a deep breath and update the question with the "all" the relevant information.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi ok gimme a few minutes, thanks

Comment: ok ive added all changes to the question @TedLyngmo

Comment: You say that "_`{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}`_" is an exception, but is it really? That looks like a JSON response from somewhere.

Instead of these snippets of code, please make a [mre]. It'll be easier to test.

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh sorry, i didnt realise. It must be a response from discord then

Comment: Much better - then, is it possible that the JSON you send is lacking information that discord needs?

Comment: ok thanks for the help @TedLyngmo ill try some stuff

Comment: `data.dump().data()` stores a pointer to the data of the temporary string returned from `dump()` so your cose has undefined behaviour